# add dynamic input field with unique id for counting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a code to calculate the total price of services.

Now if I add the hours (like 2) and add the price per hour (like 20) the code has to calculate the price that will become the subtotal. After that It calculate the "BTW" (tax) and add it to the subtotal for the total price.

What I would like is to add dynamic new input fields with a unique id so the code can calculate multiple services. So for each service you've got a total amount which all combined will be the subtotal. My code for now:

HTML

```
<table class="table-responsive table" id="table-diensten">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>amount</th>
            <th>total</th>
            <th>BTW</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-body">
        <tr class="table-row">
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="time (in hours)" id="time" onchange="totalofferte()"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="service"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cost (per hour)" id="cost" onchange="totalofferte()"></td>
            <td>&euro; <span id="total">0,00</span></td>
            <td>21%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><strong>Subtotaal</strong></td>
            <td>&euro; <span id="subtotal">0,00</span></td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td>21% BTW</td>
            <td>&euro; <span id="costbtw">0,00</span></td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td class="table-total"><span class="total">Totaal</span></td>
            <td class="table-total"><span class="total">&euro; <span id="totalofferte">0,00</span></span></td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>


</table>

<a href="#table-diensten" class="add-tablerow btn btn-default" >add new service</a>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">


function totalofferte() {

    var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;
    var time = document.getElementById('time').value;

    if (cost > 0 && time > 0) {

        var total = cost * time;

        if (total > 0) {
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;

            var subtotal = total;

            if (subtotal > 0) {
                document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML = subtotal;

                var costbtw = subtotal / 100 * 21;

                document.getElementById('costbtw').innerHTML = costbtw;

                var totalofferte = subtotal + costbtw;

                document.getElementById('totalofferte').innerHTML = totalofferte;
            }


        }

    }



}

</script>
```

Edit:

Forgot my JQuery

```
$(".add-tablerow").click(function(){
    $( ".table-body" ).append("<tr class='table-row'><td><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Tijd'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Omschrijving'></td><td><input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Kosten'></td><td>&euro; 0,00</td><td>21%</td></tr>");
});
```

Comment: why don't u use class instead of id? that would solve your problem

Comment: My problem is that I do know how to add another row, but I don't know how to add a dynamic id/class to the inputs in the row so i can call it in my JS

Comment: Maybe the source code in this answer will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669941/calulate-function-in-javascript-for-dynamically-added-field/35676764#35676764 this dynamically creates elements and calculates each price with the sub total.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using addNewRow method you can achieve the behaviour you are expecting

```js
function addNewRow(){
  var presentRows = $("#table-diensten > tbody > tr");
  var newRowId = presentRows.length + 1;
  $("#table-diensten").append(
    '<tr id="' + newRowId + '">' + 
    '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="time_' + newRowId + '" id="time_' + newRowId + '"/></td>' +
    '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="service_' + newRowId + '" id="service_' + newRowId + '"/></td>' +
    '<td><input class="form-control" type="number" name="amount' + newRowId + '" id="amount' + newRowId + '"/></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '<td></td>' +
    '</tr>'
  );
}

function totalofferte() {

    var cost = document.getElementById('cost').value;
    var time = document.getElementById('time').value;

    if (cost > 0 && time > 0) {

        var total = cost * time;

        if (total > 0) {
            document.getElementById('total').innerHTML = total;

            var subtotal = total;

            if (subtotal > 0) {
                document.getElementById('subtotal').innerHTML = subtotal;

                var costbtw = subtotal / 100 * 21;

                document.getElementById('costbtw').innerHTML = costbtw;

                var totalofferte = subtotal + costbtw;

                document.getElementById('totalofferte').innerHTML = totalofferte;
            }


        }

    }



}
```

```css
.navigation {
  width: 300px;
}


.mainmenu, .submenu {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.mainmenu a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #CCC;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #000;
}


.mainmenu li:hover a,
.mainmenu li.active a {
    background-color: #C5C5C5;
}

.mainmenu li.active .submenu {
  display: block;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.submenu a {
  background-color: #999;
}


.submenu a:hover {
  background-color: #666;
}


.submenu {
  overflow: hidden;
  max-height: 0;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table-responsive table" id="table-diensten">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Time</th>
            <th>Service</th>
            <th>amount</th>
            <th>total</th>
            <th>BTW</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="table-body">
        <tr class="table-row">
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="time (in hours)" id="time" onchange="totalofferte()"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="service"></td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cost (per hour)" id="cost" onchange="totalofferte()"></td>
            <td>&euro; <span id="total">0,00</span></td>
            <td>21%</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td><strong>Subtotaal</strong></td>
            <td>&euro; <span id="subtotal">0,00</span></td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td>21% BTW</td>
            <td>&euro; <span id="costbtw">0,00</span></td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td> </td>
            <td class="table-total"><span class="total">Totaal</span></td>
            <td class="table-total"><span class="total">&euro; <span id="totalofferte">0,00</span></span></td>
            <td> </td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>


</table>

<a href="#table-diensten" class="add-tablerow btn btn-default" onclick="addNewRow()">add new service</a>
```

Comment: Sure why not =) nice solution

Comment: Nice, Now I have to write a code to calculate each service and than add all to each other for the subtotal :)

Answer (score 0):

its very simple. Frist create your element example:

```js
var input = $("<input/>").attr({
    name: 'EmailSend',
    type: 'text',
    value: true,
    class: "YOURClass"
    id: "YouRid"
});
```

Than append your crated input to  your wish element. example:  $( ".table-body" ).append(input)

Comment: Can this be used for more than 1 added input? I guess not since the class and id is hard coded right?

Comment: Sure you can.. you have to use loop and set id +1

Answer (score 0):

**Adding items in DOM through Javascript**

In order to add new Items in your table with Native Javascript you will have to use one of the following

- [Element.insertAdjacentHTML()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)
- [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [Node.appendChild()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

If you want to use jQuery instead then you can try

- [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)
- [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

**Add custom attributes to DOM items**

If you want to add a new attribute on a DOM element , you can do it with Native Javascript using the

- [element.setAttribute(name, value);](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)

or with jQuery

- [.attr();](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

**Loop through items**

Now in order to "process" those new values each time , you need to iterate through all your inputs and carry your calculations. Iteration can be done in Native Javascript through the use of

- [Element.getElementsByTagName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByTagName) If all inputs should be processed in your Table.
- [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) If you assign a specific class on each of your inputs and only those will be processed.

or if you want to use jQuery you could go on with

- [jQuery.each()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/)