# index not incrementing in input field

Tags: javascript

I have a button that creates two input fields on click. I want to add a unique id for each couple of inputs that is created so that I can delete them later. Currently when I add the inputs they all have the same id 0 and the index does not increment, why and how can I make it increment? Here is my code:

```
 createNewPricedRoundShareholder() {

  
    const mainParent = document.getElementById('main-parent');
    var index = 0;

    const newPlatformNameInput1 = document.createElement("input");
  newPlatformNameInput1.id = index + '_first';
  newPlatformNameInput1.value = index;
  const newPlatformNameInput2 = document.createElement("input");
  newPlatformNameInput2.id = index + '_second';
  newPlatformNameInput2.value = index;
  const deleteButton = document.createElement("button");
  deleteButton.innerText = 'delete';
  const wrapperParent = document.createElement('div');
  wrapperParent.id = index + '_parent';
  wrapperParent.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput1);
  wrapperParent.appendChild(newPlatformNameInput2);
  wrapperParent.appendChild(deleteButton);  mainParent.appendChild(wrapperParent);
  index++;
    

    }
```

and my html:

```
<div id="main-parent"></div>
```

Comment: simply use `index++` to increment

Comment: I have it in my code and it still doesn't increment correctly

Comment: But here you are not showing that. Show the original code.

Comment: Check this link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42159685/add-dynamic-input-field-with-unique-id-for-counting and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19994281/use-javascript-to-create-dynamic-input-id it may solve your problem

Comment: It is shown on the last line

Comment: Your index is local to the function so it always resets to 0 when you call it. At the end you increment it to 1 but that has no effect. You have to declare `var index = 0` outside the function.

Answer (score 0):

I know you said you want an ID so you can use it to delete your row later, but you don't actually need it. If you add this code to your function, you can delete the entire row without the need of using an ID. This code will allow you to target the specific button, then the parent of that button and remove it.

```
deleteButton.addEventListener("click",function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  e.target.parentNode.remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that is because you increase the index at the end of your function but you should increase it after creating the first input and before creating the second one

```
    [...]
    const newPlatformNameInput1 = document.createElement("input");
    newPlatformNameInput1.id = index + '_first';
    newPlatformNameInput1.value = index;
    index++;
    const newPlatformNameInput2 = document.createElement("input");
    newPlatformNameInput2.id = index + '_second';
    [...]
```